# "I keep getting (code: 3) when i should be getting (code: 0). I am running all the latest versions but I can't seem to figure it out."

Tags: python, geany

## I am new to coding but I am learning python. I am trying to run python through geany and I am using a guide book that indicates that the outcome that i should be getting is:

Hello python world!

---

(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue

Instead I am getting:

The system cannot find the path specified.

---

(program exited with code: 3)

Press any key to continue . . .

I have checked all the lines in the Set Build Commands and have tried reinstalling and starting the project over.
I am running both programs on the latest versions.
Geany (1.35) Python (3.7.3)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the code you are running and the full output of the program.

Comment: Please provide more useful information about your problem